# Why my site logo not showing in Google search  results

Tags: html, css, blogger

my site:[basketballxpress](https://www.basketballxpress.com/?m=1) is not showing site logo in Google search results only the URL

the site is a blogger site using cloud fare hosting
what will be the possible solution of the problem?

I have uploaded another new logo still not showing

Comment: What do you mean not showing your logo? Please provide the header tags you use. Also there could be indexing times to consider, displaying relevant information on search engines isn't automatic when you publish changes, there are times to index the new data

Answer (score 1):

Google’s [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search#guidelines) specify that your favicon must be 48x48, 96x96 or any other multiple of 48 pixels. Your favicon does not match this specification.